hyperledger fabric ClientHandshake
I am trying one handson session tutorial: in that at the stage of install chaincode i worked on following command then got following:
peer lifecycle chaincode install property.tar.gz --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051

but getting the error as follows:
Error: failed to retrieve endorser client for install: tls root cert file must be set

To solve above error one solution command was given and i tried it as it is as follows
peer lifecycle chaincode install property.tar.gz --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles $CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
2024-07-12 20:11:16.587 IST 0001 ERRO [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> Client TLS handshake failed after 1.564929ms with error: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2024-07-12T20:11:16+05:30 is before 2024-07-12T18:29:00Z remoteaddress=127.0.0.1:7051
2024-07-12 20:11:17.591 IST 0002 ERRO [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> Client TLS handshake failed after 2.490342ms with error: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2024-07-12T20:11:17+05:30 is before 2024-07-12T18:29:00Z remoteaddress=127.0.0.1:7051
2024-07-12 20:11:19.415 IST 0003 ERRO [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> Client TLS handshake failed after 2.247969ms with error: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2024-07-12T20:11:19+05:30 is before 2024-07-12T18:29:00Z remoteaddress=127.0.0.1:7051
Error: failed to retrieve endorser client for install: endorser client failed to connect to localhost:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

kindly let me know solution for this
I tried network down and again run it, but not worked
checked permissions. but its not working.
